# Check if a user is already Connected?

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu-17.10

It goes like this :
A server is running and a client is connected instantly.
The client then gives his ID 
which is verified by server upon verification server gives green signal to the connection to send information.

Now in this verification i want to check if a particular client ID  already has a verified connection or not.

At a single moment i want only one connection for a particular client ID
I am programming with sockets (learning) but I don't understand how to tackle this problem.

I'm using c++.(ubuntu)

Comment: keep a list of all connected clients (maybe a global map of string-> client)

Comment: yes i did thought about that. but problem is how to remove the connected client from list when there is sudden unexpected disconnection.

Comment: server will receive notification that the client disconnected (assuming this is TCP)

Comment: All [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) have ways of removing elements from them.

Comment: It's not entirely true that you will be notified of a disconnect. If the connection fails  without proper disconnect handshaking and there are no keep-alives or regular messages that can fail, it can be a long, long, long time before death is noticed.

Comment: @user4581301 It can be as long as your server's read timeout. If you set that to a long, long time, you shouldn't, and if you don't set it at all, you should.

Comment: @pm100  What would a C solution be?

Comment: @Haris - recv will return 0 length

Comment: @pm100 on a closed connection, indeed. But I was asking about the global map. :)